# Route does not identifying the scree in stacknavigation?

Tags: android, react-native, navigation

I am trying to implement stacknavigation using react-navigation. When I am creating a stacknavigation const and calling in my default screen it is giving me this error.

**Route 'Main' should declare a screen. For example:
import MyScreen from './MyScreen';
...
Home: {
screen: MyScreen,
}**

My StackNavigation code is here

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text } from 'react-native';
import Register from './Register';
import Main from './Main';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const ScreenList = StackNavigator({
    Main: {
        screen: Main,
    },
    Register: {
        screen: Register,
    },
});

export default ScreenList;
```

And this is the main and default screen

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Card, Button, CardSection } from '../components/common/Index';
import Login from '../components/Login';
import ScreenList from './ScreenList';



export default class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>  
              <Button>Register</Button>  
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with react-native-navigation not yet being compatible with React 0.52.0

More information on this issue can be found on [this specific issue tracked on Github](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/2493).

Edit: a quick fix I just implemented to unblock myself while the project contributors figure out a solid solution was to add the missing interface (ReactInstanceDevCommandsHandler.java) directly into my react-native-navigation project.